# Is the spectrum of an element in an algebra, $\sigma(x) = \{z \in\mathbb{C}: \vert z\vert\leq\Vert x \Vert\}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, banach-algebras, division-algebras

In the book, a first course in functional analysis by D.Somasundaram, it is mentioned that $\sigma(x) = \{z \in\mathbb{C}: \vert z\vert\leq\Vert x \Vert\}$
But the proof is given only for one side  inclusion..that is.,
The spectrum of an element x in a Complex Banach Algebra is a subset of the closed disk with centre $0$ and radius $\Vert x\Vert$.
Is the reverse inclusion true? So that they become equal.
(I cannot find the proof of reverse inclusion in any book so far I have seen)

Comment: It is not an equality for a general $x$.

Comment: How can i disprove it is not equal?can you please help me?

Comment: How about a matrix with $0$ as the only eigen value?

Comment: I have no clue , if you don't mind , I request you to kindly provide me the disproof please...

Comment: Your algebra is $2 \times 2$ matrices, and $A$ is a nonzero $2 \times 2$ matrix, then $\sigma(A)$ is at most $2$ points, so it is not a disk, as claimed.  We do have inclusion in one direction (which you note was proved); perhaps the statement you quote was a misprint.

Comment: As answered by my prof...They are equal because ...he picked a z from the closed disk of radius ||x|| , then we have |z|≤||x|| implies 1≤||xz-¹|| implies 1≤||e-(e-xz-¹)|| implies (e-xz-¹) is singular ...which implies x-ze is singular...thus z is in spectrum of x and hence they are equal..       this js how i have been responded for my doubt.

Comment: Tell your prof that $1≤||e-y||$ does *not* imply $y$ is singular (counterexample: $y=2e$). He probably confuses with the converse, i.e. $1>||e-y||$ implies $y$ is regular. As for the main claim of equality, a simpler counterexample is $$\sigma(e)=\{1\}\subsetneq\{z\in\Bbb Z\mid|z|\le1\}$$

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spectrum of an element x denoted by sigma(x)={z : (x-ze)is singular} is a closed and bounded subset of the complex plane and it is only a subset of the closed disk of radius ||x|| and not equal to the disk of radius ||x||.
It may be either a notational complexity of the  book or a misprint that the spectrum of an element x in an algebra equals the closed disk of radius||x||.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).